# How can I make my Lambda function talk to a server running on my local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localhost

I am creating a Lambda function that makes a call to some functionality on my server.

I would like to test the Lambda function against a local instance of my server, so that I don't have to deploy to AWS in order to test run the whole flow.

Is there any way to call my local machine's development server from inside Lambda without having to keep deploying to AWS (or some other remote server)?

Comment: You might also want to look at options to test your Lambda function locally, including SAM Local and various GitHub projects.

Comment: So why can't the server functions be tested without Lambda?  It is just going to do http[s] calls to the server anyway right?  Can those be tested outside the lambda environment?

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible if you set up a VPN or Direct Connect between your VPC and your local network.

But honestly, this will probably be more expensive and more complex than simply deploying to an EC2 instance.  Automating deployment should be simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Too little info. It depends on how your lambda is configured. If it's in a VPC then how that VPC is configured. Whether your laptop has static IP, if it's sitting behind firewalls.

In general what you need is:

- your service exposed to Internet:

  - a public IP for your local machine
  - ports (on which your service is exposed) opened up the if blocked by firewall etc.
- your lambda has Internet access (route, security-group/acl/gateways):

  - if lambda is in public subnet, see AWS doc on how to setup IGW.
  - if it's in private subnet, see AWS doc on how to setup NAT GW.

Else if your laptop is inside some special secure network then VPN as chris suggested, which make sure your service is NOT exposed to Internet.

Some links that might help:

- Setup [Internet access for your lambdas](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) in VPC.
- Setup [Internet access for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-internet).
- Setup [VPC for VPN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html) access.

Answer (score 0):

I will write specific to the Java language:

AWS Lambda functions are plain old Java objects so you can write unit tests to trigger them locally. Even if you are using the RequestHandler interface which requires the entry point of the function to provide the

public O handleRequest(I input, Context context);

method and if you are using the context variable you can easily mock that like for example:

```
@Test
public void testAddAddressHandlerDevStage() throws Exception {
    Context context = mock(Context.class);       
   when(context.getInvokedFunctionArn()).thenReturn("arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:updateAddress:TEST");

    Address newAddress = new Address();
    new AddAddress().handleRequest(newAddress, context);
    assertNotNull(newAddress.getId());
}
```

If you write unit tests like this you can also trigger them via a CI tool like Jenkins on a test server.

So the above test works with TEST env variables but you can write a configuration for DEV environment too. Java language provides richer tools for such generalizations and abstractions compared to most interpreted language.

Answer (score 0):

If your local machine is publicly reachable and your server is callable on an open port then I don't see why it wouldn't just work.  Maybe DynDNS hack would work if it is not publicly accessible.

Are you mainly concerned with having your favorite IDE for debugging?    If not then it is cheap to set up EC2 server that you only spin up for testing.  No charge when not in use.  Or maybe checkout out [AWS workspaces](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/) if you need a richer environment for testing and debugging this.

Also remember your EC2 instances can have Route 53 private host zone mapping an arbirtrary url to your instance which makes things a bit cleaner and closer to production.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a tunneling service like https://tunnelto.dev/ and tunnel your local server. This makes it so that your local server will be available on the IP of the tunnel.

I've used this method in a app that I was working on.