# Communication between Amazon Lambda and Windows Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am a newbie to AWS and cloud computing in general, so I apologize if this question is foolish.

I am currently working on developing an app for Amazon Echo that would allow it to remotely control a PC (i.e. change volume, pause a movie, etc.). My problem is that I do not know how to communicate between my Amazon Lambda service and my Windows Application.
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my Lambda function talk to a server running on my local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325388/how-can-i-make-my-lambda-function-talk-to-a-server-running-on-my-local-machine)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326736/496289

Comment: I don't think this is a clear duplicate of the other question, even though answers to that question would be potentially helpful in clarifying what needs to happen, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are potentially some problems with the way you have posed the question -- how to communicate between a Lambda Function and a Windows machine could involve a number of different solutions, but what you are looking for (as far as I can tell) is a more specific -- yet simultaneously more generalizable -- solution.

Are you trying to actually make an Alexa skill that users could use, or just something for yourself? It makes a big difference, because for just yourself there are a number of hacky solutions you could implement, like port forwarding and dynamic DNS, which fail dramatically if you try to do them in the real world.  You need another component -- some kind of real-time push messaging -- that bridges between an "agent" in your Windows app and requests emitted by your Lambda code.

Your actual problem to solve is not so much how to communicate between AWS Lambda and a Windows Application, but rather one of a need for understanding how a platform like Alexa needs to communicate with a "smart home" device, specifically an [entertainment device](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/build-smart-home-skills-for-entertainment-devices.html).

It is a relatively complicated undertaking, because -- fundamentally -- there is no way of communicating directly between Lambda and an arbitrary device out on the Internet.  Dynamic IP addresses, network address translation (NAT), firewalls, security considerations, and other factors make it impossible to reliably initiate a connection from a Lambda function (or indeed from any Internet connected device) to any other arbitrary destination device.  Most devices (my phone, my Alexa-controlled light switch, my Windows laptop) are running behind a boundary that assumes requests are initiated behind the boundary.  When I open web sites, stream video, etc., I initiate the request and the response returns on the channel (often a TCP connection) that I have created, from behind my boundary (e.g. the router in my cable modem) that doesn't allow external initiation of TCP connections.  They are bidirectional once established, but must be initiated from inside.

Of course, you can statically "poke a hole" in your router configuration by forwarding a specific TCP port to a specific internal (usually private) IP address, which works as long as your Internet provider doesn't change your IP address, and your internal device doesn't get a new IP address... and there'a [UPnP NAT Traversal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal), which seems like a good solution until you realize that it is also terrible (though for a "hobbyist" application, it could work).

While this is a long and complex topic, the short answer is that Alexa, via Lambda code, is only capable of initiating connections, and your device, wherever it may be, is only capable of initiating connections -- not receiving them... and thus you need some kind of "meet in the middle" solution: something that allows the device to maintain its "connection" to a central "service" that can coordinate the interactions on demand.

For example:

> AWS IoT Core is a managed cloud platform that lets connected devices easily and securely interact with cloud applications and other devices. AWS IoT Core can support billions of devices and trillions of messages, and can process and route those messages to AWS endpoints and to other devices reliably and securely. With AWS IoT Core, your applications can keep track of and communicate with all your devices, all the time, even when they aren’t connected.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/

The client initiates the connection (e.g. via a web socket) to the IoT platform, and maintains it, so that when a message arrives at IoT, the service knows how to deliver that message to the client when it's received.  ("even when they aren't online" refers to the "device shadow" capability, which allows you to programmatically interact with a proxy for the device, e.g. knowing the last temperature setting of a thermostat, and asking the thermostat to change its set point when the connection is re-established at some future point).

Or, potentially something like this:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.
>
> Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync.
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Both of these potential solutions solve the problem by "knowing how to contact" arbitrary devices, wherever they may be... and I would suggest that this is the core of your actual need.

There are a lot of alternatives for such a "service," including roll-your-own websocket or HTML EventSource implementations with servers... the purpose of this is not product recommendations but rather to give you an idea of what you would need for such a scenario -- an intermediate platform that can be interacted with by the Lambda code, which also knows how to communicate with "agent" code running on the device... because both Lambda and the agent need to initiate the communication channels and thus additional components are required to bridge them together.